# Stack Exchange-like open-source platform where questions are suggestions and answers are input, never solutions

Tags: software-development, open-source, web-development, collaboration, web-services

I want a platform for my site where users can make suggestions on how our organization can improve. This is because good ideas are sometimes lost because the holders of the ideas don't want attention around themselves. This issue is eliminated by having an anonymous platform for collaborative revision and feedback. The QA model with the modifications described in the title would be suitable, I believe. Are there any Open-Source QA platforms that allow such modification? Else, are there other platforms that would satisfy my needs?

Comment: Ummmm I've a feeling that your question is off topic here

Comment: @Mr.Alien First, I started at StackOverflow, was repointed to Meta, then repointed here. Where do you suggest I go?

Comment: The platform you are looking for are generally programmed on custom basis, here we recommend generalized solutions and not specific to the user :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I am 99% sure this is on-topic.

Comment: @bslfakbefki: By open source, do you mean both GPL-type AGPL-style license are OK? Also, could you please describe the lifecycle? Anonymous user posts an idea. Anyone can add "input". No need for Stackexchange-style comments, right? Do you need votes? Is the content public? Can anyone register? Can anyone participate at the same level? We can't answer without answers to all of these questions.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Source must be completely open, meaning I need to go through no paperwork or communication with the project, such as is the case with DokuWiki and Question2Answer. Anonymous users (as in no full name required) posts an idea. Anyone can comment on the idea and revise the idea itself and the comments. Votes are needed. Content is public, anyone can register and everyone can participate on the same level.

Comment: What exactly is wrong/missing with [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) (or any other [Q&A platform](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/193139))? -- Would a [forum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum) with voting functionality be a solution?

Comment: Some ideas: [Simple tool to manage Question and Answer](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/a/8684/2476).

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [Osqa](http://www.osqa.net/)? I've noticed a few sites that have been using it for similar purposes. Out of the box it seems a pretty good stackexchange clone. Given a little styling to look more like a suggestions site and some adjustments to the settings to do things like turn off answers and enable comments only could make it fit your requirements a little better.

Comment: OSQA is now part of [AnswerHub](http://dzonesoftware.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of what a "question" means and what an "answer" is, is really up to you. Just explain to your colleagues how to use the system.

Before you get 33 more answers, I'll link to the Meta StackExchange [answer for Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/245641), which is probably the most complete list available so far.

Personally I have [Questions2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) up and running. Installation and setup was very easy, but I couldn't get LDAP to work.

Answer (score 0):

With [Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io/), you can create topics of type *Idea*. Then, people's replies are feedback and thoughts about the idea. The discussion behaves as in a Question-Answers topic: people reply (post "comments") to the feedback, and a feedback reply and related comments, are grouped together, and the insightful (upvoted) thoughts surface to the top.

Talkyard is [open source, GitHub repo](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard); I'm developing Talkyard. Here's a screenshot of an *Idea* topic:

---

[image: A topic of type Idea, with feedback and replies]

---

Once you've started actually implementing an Idea, you can optionally change the status of the Idea topic, to Planned, and then Doing and Done:

---

[image: Topic status changed to Doing Now]

---

... then people will see at a glance (also on the topic list page) that *"Oh they've started doing this already"*.

You can append Progress Notes at the bottom of the page, describing your progress with making the idea happen:

---

[image: Progress notes]

---

Talkyard supports Question-Answers topics too (there's a per category default topic type setting — e.g. *Idea* or *Question*). And open-ended discussions, if you want to talk about news and blog posts.